# WinForms WebBrowser HTMLDocument strips tags

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I am having issues working with the HtmlDocument object that is contained/provided with the WebBrowser control.

It seems that when i use `GetElementsByTagName("ol")` , the returned result is actually a stripped down version of what the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` property contains. Is there a reason for this? Am I doing something wrong to get the elements out?

Here's an example:

```
string html = "<html><head></head><body><ol type=\"i\"><li>SomeItem</li></ol></body></html>";

//this part allows me to load the HTML into the HtmlDocument of the WebBrowser control,
// without having to render the control on a form
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
this.webBrowser1.Document.Write(html);

//then i get the document object in order to work with the elements properly.
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;

//then i get the lists contained in that document... and play with those.
HtmlElementCollection ol_lists = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ol");
foreach(HtmlElement ol in ol_lists)
{
    string type = ol.GetAttribute("type");
}
```

This code example actually gives me this within `type`:

```
""
```

Then, if i do this in order to see why it's actually empty:

```
string outer_html = ol.OuterHtml;
```

I get the following result:

```html
<OL><LI>SomeItem</LI></OL>
```

Which is obviously not what is in the web browser... because if i do this:

```
string text = this.webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

I get this result:

```html
<html><head></head><body><ol type="i"><li>SomeItem</li></ol></body></html>
```

And if i let the code run through and display the HTML contents into the browser control, it actually displays a list with roman numerals for its items... so obviously my html code made it in there ok... what am i doing wrong? How can i get back the actual element properties and everything else from the HtmlDocument object?